# How to connect the Pi to a PC?

Tags: vnc

My Raspberry Pi starts a VNC server on port 5901 on boot, but currently I do not have a display to access the GUI. I do however have an Ethernet cable and a PC with the VNC client software, how do I access the GUI from my PC?

Comment: First of all you have to login to the Pi from your PC.  Search for headless Pi and login.  Then you need to set up VNC on the Pi.  Again search.

Comment: You can start VNC on boot, but it won't show you anything. As @joan says, you should log on to the Pi (headless or not) the start VNC as a user.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that I had access to the GUI on the vnc client but on rebooting the pi the connection using the vnc client gets rejected by the remote device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got access to the pi by running a scan using *Find My Pi* (https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-Pi-Finder/releases/tag/v2.0.1-beta), all I had to do was note down the IP of the pi after the detection by this tool. I used this IP to get access of the SSH terminal. The next thing I did was set up a static IP as in http://www.modmypi.com/blog/tutorial-how-to-give-your-raspberry-pi-a-static-ip-address. 
Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 0):

Since your Pi already starts a VNC server on boot, just use a VNC viewer on your PC as follows:

Make sure your Pi is correctly on the network and that you can `SSH` into it. There is plenty of information out there for this so I'll skip that.

Connect to that server with some VNC viewer.

This is very easy on Mac OSX:
Open a new `Finder -> Go -> Connect To Server -> Enter the IP address and port` (e.g. `192.168.0.1:5901`)

Alternatively, download software such as [VNC Viewer](https://www.realvnc.com/download/) and follow the instructions there.

Comment: I'm on windows. In cmd when I hit ipconfig and check the IP dynamically allotted to the Ethernet port, its of the form 168.***.***.*.* . But when I use this IP in putty to access the ssh it says that the remote device rejected the connection. (I'm using port 22 for ssh)